# dynamic addEventListener with argument

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

Im trying to dinamically insert names into the value of an input element. I try to pass players[i] as an argument for the function addPlayer but it says undefined. When I click on each name it should be passing it to the input field. Where am I failing?

```
var players = ["john","doe"];

function addPlayer(str) {
    console.log(str);
    document.getElementsByClassName("answerInput")[0].value += str;
}


for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(players[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    node.classList.add("newPlayers");
    document.getElementById("pushPlayer").appendChild(node);
    node.addEventListener('click', function () {
           addPlayer(players[i]);
        }, false);
};
```

Comment: You have a closure around the `i` variable, which means that when any node gets clicked, `i` will be the last value the loop assigned to it and all nodes will share that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable `i` declared with the keyword `var`

> The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, so, the variable `i` will end the `for-loop` with the last value.

```js
var players = ["john (click me)", "doe (click me)"];

for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(players[i]);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.classList.add("newPlayers");
  document.getElementById("pushPlayer").appendChild(node);
  node.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(i)
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<div id='pushPlayer'>
</div>
```

An alternative is declaring that variable with the statement `let`

> Variables declared by `let` have as their scope the block in which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks. In this way, `let` works very much like `var`. The main difference is that **the scope of a `var` variable is the entire enclosing function**.

```js
var players = ["john", "doe"];

function addPlayer(str) {
  console.log(str);
  document.getElementsByClassName("answerInput")[0].value += str;
}

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(players[i]);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.classList.add("newPlayers");
  document.getElementById("pushPlayer").appendChild(node);
  node.addEventListener('click', function() {
      addPlayer(players[i]);
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<input class='answerInput' placeholder='Enter answer'>
<div id='pushPlayer'>
</div>
```

Another alternative is using **[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)** to return a function with a specific value/player.

```js
var players = ["john", "doe"];

function addPlayer(str) {
  console.log(str);
  document.getElementsByClassName("answerInput")[0].value += str;
}

for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(players[i]);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.classList.add("newPlayers");
  document.getElementById("pushPlayer").appendChild(node);
  node.addEventListener('click', (function(player) {
    return function () {
      addPlayer(player);
    }
  })(players[i]), false);
};
```

```html
<input class='answerInput' placeholder='Enter answer'>
<div id='pushPlayer'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions! It works perfectly :)